# asp.net mvc Redirect the user back to the view page where he comes through?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

User can go to the same view page from different paths:

from path 1 as menu1>submenu1>viewpage1,

or from path 2 as menu2>submenu2>viewpage1.

On the viewpage1 there is a save/submit button, when user clicks, it should go back to the path when he came through, that means if he came through path1, it should go back to submenu1, if he came through path2, it should go back to subememu 2.

Where should I write this path? in the controller? or in the view page?

what methode should I use for writing this path? How to write this path?

I'm new to MVC C#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Where will you send the user if they come to viewpage1 by typing/pasting its url in the browser address bar? You are trying to shoehorn desktop mentality into web application.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saying that the user simply comes to viewpage1 by browsing through one of two different dropdown site menus, then there's not much you *can* do. There's not going to be any record of *how* the user chose that link, only that they got there somehow. The only thing you *could* potentially do in this situation is differentiate the two versions of the link somehow. The easiest would be by just appending a query string:

```
menu1
    submenu1
        viewpage1 (?menu=1)
menu2
    submenu2
        viewpage1 (?menu=2)
```

Then, you can use that query string value to determine which page to redirect back to.

You could also use a completely different URL for the two versions of viewpage1. Either way, though, it will then appear as duplicate content by search engine bots, so you should add `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` to the page's head, where the value for `href` would be the link you want as the "main" or "primary" version.